# Laravel Project not updating Custom fonts?

Tags: laravel, fonts

So I'm facing an odd case. So i have uploaded Fonts in Public/fonts directory (
[this is where i have uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZCxF.png)
screenshot attached). Then when i use it in blade for example it does not show on live website. My website is on shared hosting.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Dashboard 1')
@section('contents')
    {{--<dashboard></dashboard>--}}
    Murshalin

<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: Lestudio;
    src: url('{{ public_path('fonts/bpg-le-studio-02-webfont.tff') }}');
}
</style>
@endsection
```

Like here for example it does not affect anything I also have it in core.scss file imported but nothing changes. am I missing something?

It does not show in source too : [Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu1lN.png)

Comment: According to your screenshot it's `bpg-le-studio-02-webfont.ttf`, not `bpg-le-studio-02-webfont.ttf.tff`

Comment: yep that was an error indeed :) but not the issue does not fix for some rason :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in core.css file i imported web font using cdn

```
@import url("//cdn.web-fonts.ge/fonts/etc");
```

and just used font-family

This worked for me.